# PYTHON: double-underscore prefixed parameter in *function*

Tags: python, cpython

belows is in `builtins.pyi`

```py
def max(__arg1: _T, __arg2: _T, *_args: _T, key: Callable[[_T], SupportsLessThan]) -> _T:
```

I do know what the name mangling means and know that the name mangling will influence every "__xxx" identifier as long as in class definition field.

So I have three questions:

- why there paramters "__arg1" "__arg2" used the "__xxx" pattern and parameter "key" not;
- what is the function and purpose of "__xxx" pattern specially used in the function's parameter or in this case;
- I feel awkward to find the implementation of name mangling, and could you tell me where it is in cpython source code.

Many thanks.

further work:

```py
def wat1(__a):
    def wat2(__b):
        return __b, __a
    return __a

print(wat1.__code__.co_varnames)
print(wat1.__code__.co_cellvars)
dis.dis(wat1)
```

output(linux python==3.10.8):

```py
('__a', 'wat2')
('__a',)

21           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (__a)
              2 RETURN_VALUE

22           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (__b)
              2 LOAD_DEREF               0 (__a)
              4 BUILD_TUPLE              2
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name mangling applies only to names used in a class definition, not function parameters. In this case the leading underscores are only a naming convention to indicate that parameters with such names are not to be passed with keyword arguments, but rather only positional ones.

This is to say that you should call `max` with:

```
max(1, 2)
```

rather than:

```
max(__arg1=1, __arg2=2)
```

The `key` argument on the other hand, are named without an underscore prefix, indicating that it is meant to be passed with a keyword argument:

```
max(1, -2, key=abs)
```

Comment: BTW, this was all implemented before the introduction of [positional only arguments](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/) in Python. For new development, those would be preferred instead of the old naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for [@blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6890912/blhsing)'s answer and [@zvone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389289/zvone)'s comment, to summarize the above, I' d like to share my understand of it.
Here is cpython source code part of `max()` :

```c
static PyObject *
min_max(PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds, int op)
{
    PyObject *v;
    static char *kwlist[] = {"key", "default", NULL};
    const int positional = PyTuple_Size(args) > 1;
    int ret;

    if (positional) {
        v = args;
    }
    else if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, name, 1, 1, &v)) {
        if (PyExceptionClass_Check(PyExc_TypeError)) {
            PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "%s expected at least 1 argument, got 0", name);
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```

If using keyword argument to pass args to `max()`, arguments here will drop in `PyObject* kwds` rather than `PyObject* args` so `PyArg_UnpackTuple` will get nothing and return false, then raise a `TypeError` in python level as expected.

**So it's a powerful purpose to use positional one here?**

Also it's just a convention now with no constraint but [new positional only arguments syntax](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/) do restrict. So belows is possible.

```py
def wat1(__a):
    return __a
wat1(__a=1)
```

New one would be preferred instead of the old naming convention because it make input arguments more contrllable.

For some reason `builtin.pyi` don't apply this new positional syntax, maybe historical issues? I cannot figure it out.